# Validation for uniqueness not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called as `Template` which has `self referential has-many through` association with a join model called as `RelatedTemplate`.

The `Template` model is written like this:

```
has_many :related_templates, :foreign_key => :parent_id
has_many :children, :through => :related_templates, :source => :child

has_many :inverse_related_templates, class_name: "RelatedTemplate", :foreign_key => :child_id
has_many :parents, :through => :inverse_related_templates, :source => :parent

validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
               length: { maximum: 100, too_long: "should be maximum %{count} characters" }
```

The join-model `RelatedTemplate` is:

```
 belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Template'
 belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Template'
```

In the console when i tried to create a child template with the same name as the parent name then the validation doesn't work:

```
rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.2.5)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> a = Template.new
=> #<Template id: nil, client_id: nil, something_id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, another_something_id: nil, video_id: nil, container_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> a.something_id=1
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> a.name="Hamza"
=> "Hamza"
irb(main):004:0> a.another_something_id=16
=> 16
irb(main):005:0> a.container_id=2
=> 2
irb(main):006:0> a.children.build(name: "Hamza", another_something_id: 16, container_id: 2)
=> #<Template id: nil, client_id: nil, something_id: nil, name: "Hamza", description: nil, another_something_id: 16, video_id: nil, container_id: 2>
irb(main):007:0> a.save
(0.9ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Template Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE LOWER("templates"."name") = LOWER('Hamza') LIMIT 1
Container Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "containers".* FROM "containers" WHERE "containers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Template Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE LOWER("templates"."name") = LOWER('Hamza') LIMIT 1
Container Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "containers".* FROM "containers" WHERE "containers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "templates" ("something_id", "name", "another_something_id", "container_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["something_id", 1], ["name", "Hamza"], ["another_something_id", 16], ["container_id", 2]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "templates" ("name", "another_something_id", "container_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Hamza"], ["another_something_id", 16], ["container_id", 2]]
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "related_templates" ("parent_id", "child_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["parent_id", 156], ["child_id", 157], ["created_at", "2016-05-05 07:03:51.496346"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-05 07:03:51.496346"]]
(0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
```

Now the query:

```
irb(main):016:0> a.name
=> "Hamza"
irb(main):017:0> a.children.first.name
Template Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" INNER JOIN "related_templates" ON "templates"."id" = "related_templates"."child_id" WHERE "related_templates"."parent_id" = $1  ORDER BY "templates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 158]]
=> "Hamza"
```

Dont know what is wrong here ?

Comment: add source key to relation `has_many :related_templates, :foreign_key => :parent_id, source => :template`

Comment: I did but it doesn't work

Comment: how exactly dont work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both object only exist in memory, when you validate them. The uniqueness validation passes in both cases, because the validation checks if there is a similar record in the database already.

Have a look at the logs:

```
# you call save
irb(main):007:0> a.save
(0.9ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1

# Rails validates the first object
Template Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE LOWER("templates"."name") = LOWER('Hamza') LIMIT 1
Container Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "containers".* FROM "containers" WHERE "containers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

# Rails validates the second object
Template Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE LOWER("templates"."name") = LOWER('Hamza') LIMIT 1
Container Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "containers".* FROM "containers" WHERE "containers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

# At this point Rails thinks that both records will be fine, because the validation passed

# Rails saved the first object
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "templates" ("something_id", "name", "another_something_id", "container_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["something_id", 1], ["name", "Hamza"], ["another_something_id", 16], ["container_id", 2]]

# Rails saved the second object
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "templates" ("name", "another_something_id", "container_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Hamza"], ["another_something_id", 16], ["container_id", 2]]
```

This is good example why Rails uniqueness validations are not 100% secure. Another example might be race conditions, when multiple requests hit the application at the same time.

The only way to avoid this kind of problems, is to add a unique index to the database table.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll add the uniqueness constraint at the db table. May be then i need to handle that `database constraint error` manually. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to handle the database error yourself.